# mysql doesn't start properly due to ib_logfile issue

Tags: mysql

When i try to start `mysql`, i get the following error:

```
170228 15:14:38  mysqld started
InnoDB: Error: log file ./ib_logfile2 is of different size 0 0 bytes
InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 5242880 bytes!
170228 15:14:38 Can't init databases
170228 15:14:38 Aborting

170228 15:14:38  InnoDB: Warning: shutting down a not properly started
                 InnoDB: or created database!
170228 15:14:38 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown Complete

170228 15:14:38  mysqld ended
```

When i delete this log file, as i understand i should do in order to fix it, i get the follofwing error:

```
170228 15:21:39  mysqld started
170228 15:21:39  InnoDB: Log file ./ib_logfile2 did not exist: new to be created
170228 15:21:39 Can't init databases
170228 15:21:39 Aborting

170228 15:21:39  InnoDB: Warning: shutting down a not properly started
                 InnoDB: or created database!
170228 15:21:39 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown Complete

170228 15:21:39  mysqld ended
```

After that i actually return the original situation, where "ib_logfile2 is of different size 0 0 bytes".

How can i fix this issue?

**Edit**:
Here is my DB data folder:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql mysql         132 Feb 27 15:38 forum_test
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql 10737418240 Feb 27 15:41 ibdata1
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql 10737418240 Feb 27 15:33 ibdata2
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql 10737418240 Feb 27 15:31 ibdata3
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql 10737418240 Feb 27 15:37 ibdata4
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql 10737418240 Feb 27 15:35 ibdata5
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql     5242880 Feb 27 19:03 ib_logfile0
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql     5242880 Feb 27 16:20 ib_logfile1
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql           0 Feb 28 15:21 ib_logfile2
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql       21076 Feb 27 18:58 my.cnf_abc
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql mysql        4096 Feb 27 15:37 mysql
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql mysql         102 Feb 27 15:39 test
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql mysql       16384 Feb 27 15:39 abc
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql mysql        4096 Feb 27 15:37 abcAdv
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql mysql       36864 Feb 27 15:39 abcExcel
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql mysql          81 Feb 27 15:37 abcHul
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql mysql        4096 Feb 27 15:39 abcMesh
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql mysql        4096 Feb 27 15:39 abcMilt
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql        4603 Feb 28 15:21 abc-restore180.log
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql mysql        4096 Feb 27 15:39 abcSold
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql mysql         137 Feb 27 15:39 abcVod
```

Comment: No space left on the device or permissions issues ?

Comment: No. I have enough space, and a proper permissions.

Comment: Can you update your question with `ls -l` output ?

Comment: @pawel7318 Done

Comment: `sudo -i -u mysql` than try to go that location and write something in to that file

Comment: I'm not able. I get `This account is currently not available`.

Comment: Try `su - mysql` and make sure that `mysql` account has some shell set at `/etc/passwd`. I still belive that the file is created by `root` on startup (even with `mysql` owner) but the `mysql` user is not able to write into it. This all is just to check if that's true.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you cause I use Windows and not Ubuntu like almost every other user here. So anyway, go to the `C:/xampp/mysql/data/` directory and change "`ibdata1`" to "`ibdata1---`" or rather add "---" to "`ibdata1`" and restart `xampp` and `mysql`
It will create a new ibdata1 file when you run `mysql` and start working normally.
Hope this helps :)